# How to get path of children when parent is selected in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm trying to get the path of the parent and children nodes when the parent is selected. To get the path of the node selected I did the following:

```
 $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree({
    "core" : {
       "data" : {
          "type" : "POST",
          "url" : "myurl.php",
          "data" : function (node) {
                  return { "id" : node.id };
              }
       },
       "dataType" : "json",
    },
    "plugins" : [ "wholerow", "checkbox", "types" ]
 })
 .on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var path = $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree(true).get_path(data.node,"/");
    console.log ("path = " + path + "\n");
 });""
```

But I don't know how to get the path the children's parent.

I tried to get the id's of children's parent and then apply the `split()`function to get the id's and then apply the `get_path()` but this is not working, because it said that `split` is not a function.

```
var test = data.node.children;
var spt_tst = test.split(',');
alert("node = " + spt_tst[0]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**** EDIT ****

My tree is like in the image:
[image]

What I want to do is: select the folder **images** and the get the path of all the content, for example, I want to get the path of the things that are inside **.xvpics** folder and the others too. Because I will have to send these paths to an .txt file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.node.children`returns an array, which you can access by index. To get the i-th element use `data.node.children[i]`. For example, to iterate over all children of `data.node`do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.node.children.length; i++) {
  //for example call get_path of the child
  var path = $(\'#jstree_demo_div\').jstree(true).get_path(data.node.children[i],"/");
}
```

I hope I understood you right and that is what you are looking for.

EDIT: You can use `children_d` to get all children of the node. Even the children of the children.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.node.children_d.length; i++) {
  //for example call get_path of the child
  var path = $(\'#jstree_demo_div\').jstree(true).get_path(data.node.children_d[i],"/");
}
```

Hope I got you right this time. Just let me know if not.

Comment: Thanks for reply @oerl ! I think I didn't explain right, because that you didn't understand what I am trying to do. I already tried what you said, but this is not what I'm looking for, I will update my question.

Comment: Updated my answer too. Maybe you can use `children_d`. Please have a look.