# why I am getting this error "undefined is not a function "

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using copy node functionality of jstree .While using that I am getting this "error undefined is not a function".I need to copy "b" having all childs node on same level.
Here is fiddle.I am reading Api from here
http://www.jstree.com/api/

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/195/

```
$("#copyNode").on("click", function () {
     $('#tree').jstree(true).copy_node ("#b")

});
```

Comment: Fiddle seems to be working for me. When do you get this error?

Comment: it is not coppy when user click "copy button"

Comment: when you click button then you find this error

Comment: I need to copy the whole "b" node and display it after "b"..like as we do in copy the folder

Comment: @shaunakde why it is not copying the "b" node

Comment: Not getting any error. Error may have appeared due to late loading of js

Comment: Undefined isn't function, means you are calling a nonexistent function

Comment: ok ...can we copy the node ..and paste on tree view "b" node as given in api

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti can we copy the "b" node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the API carefully. It points out that you have to specify the new parent of the copied node. 
For example this statement copies the node `b` under `root0`:

```
$('#tree').jstree(true).copy_node ("#b","root0")
```

Also here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLyW8/2/

Comment: can we give new Id to copied "b"

Comment: I would do that in the callback function. Look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLyW8/5/

Comment: if you change id it will not expand .Also I need to change ID of all inner childs of copied "b"  node

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me. Please create one and we can have a look.

Comment: Just add copy text in ID of copy node with same id of b node .Example "copy_b" ,"copy_b-a-1","copy_b-b-2","copy_b-b-a"..so on

Comment: stackoverflow team not allowed only allowed after 60 min ..:(

Comment: Fixed the bug that the node cannot be expanded after setting id. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/NLyW8/7/. To rename the child nodes you have to iterate through the children of the node. To get the children use `node.children` and look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829903/how-to-get-path-of-children-when-parent-is-selected-in-jstree/23841776#23841776